# HC-12 detection by Raspberry Pi bluetooth scanner

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I have bought an HC-12 module, but as much as I have investigated I have not found a way that a Raspberry Pi with a bluetooth detector called bluelog can detect it.

What do I have to do so that HC-12 wired to a Arduino can be detected with the bluetooth scanner?

How to set HC-12 in 'discoverable' mode?

Thank you

Comment: According to https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/understanding-and-implementing-the-hc-12-wireless-transceiver-module/ the HC-12 is not a Bluetooth module. Did my search return the wrong module? It appears you would normally buy them in pairs and have one on the Arduino and one on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

HC12 is a 433MHz transceiver. Bluetooth operates at 2.4GHz

What you're trying to do is impossible and doesn't make any sense.

There are other modules like HC05 or HC06 that communicate via Bluetooth. Your HC12 does not. You'll need a second of those transceivers to establish a connection between the Arduino and Raspberry PI.

This will give you up to 1km of range at lower bandwidth while Bluetooth only works across several meters.

So pick whatever suits your requirements best. A HC12 alone won't do much.

Maybe you should spend a few minutes on researching how radio transmission works befor you buy any equipment.